# Unable to run asp.net development server

Tags: asp.net, compiler-errors, server

I installed VS 2013 on Windows 10 and I am trying to execute my ASP.Net program following error is showing.

[image]

After that reset windows 10. Then installed new VS 2013 ultimate. Then created simple **HelloWorld** program with 
C#

> Web 
>   ASP.NET Web Application.

Still error remain.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: There are A LOT of results if you google search the error.  Have you tried all of these fixes?

Comment: Is it fixed when you reboot your system?

Comment: I have tried that but not working

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 no longer ships ASP.NET Development Server, so revise the title please.

Comment: Use Jexus Manager to open the web site in global IIS Express node and see if any error would be reported, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/getting-started/features.html#global-iis-express